# How to profile code during unit test with Nosetests?

Tags: python, nosetests

I have looked at `--with-timer` and `--with-profile` to profile my tests but these options either give too little info or too much info.

Example, if I have the following test:

```
def test_foo():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
```

I just want to profile how long each function call or each line within the test took.  So the output will be something like:

```
   do_something() : .5 seconds
   do_something_else() : .5 seconds
   test_foo() : 1 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this [talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nose-users/rVFBXRS9oG4), you could user the Xunit plugin and post-process its xml

Use --with-xunit and the following code to process nosetests.xml

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import parse 
from operator import itemgetter 

elems = parse(open("nosetests.xml")).getiterator("testcase") 
tests = sorted(((e.get("name"), int(e.get("time"))) for e in elems), 
               key=itemgetter(1), reverse=1) 

for test in (test for test in tests if test[1]): 
    print "%s: %s sec" % test
```

Comment: This can easily be archived by using `--with-timer`

Comment: thanks - there's no `--with-timer` option for my version of nosetests so this does the trick. Note - i had to change `int` to `float` too though.